# Responsive design: trouble with resolution in px and inches

Tags: responsive-design

I made my site responsive BUT I have this issue about the resolutions. See at the breaking point of 1024x768 the design looks fine, by this I mean when you resize your browser. The problem is I noticed in IE 8 that the site looks fine in this resolution, but if I see it with the size of 6" it looks awful.

Is it important too to consider the device size in inches as well? Or should I just consider the px size? Right now I'm having 2 versions and I don't know which one should I keep.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to account both for resolution, and for physical screen size.

Imagine if your site were displayed on a 1024x768 screen that's on a watch-face (say, 1x1") - would it still look appropriate?

On a more practical note, you will never be able to 100% account for all possible screen/resolution sizes. Design your ui so that it presents the most-usable-presentable possible interface, for a given resolution/size combination.